# Scrollable columns in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tabulator

If my tabulator http://tabulator.info/ column is too long, how can i add scrollable functionality to that column? Resizable rows option allows the user to resize and see all the content, but can a scroll bar for that column be included?

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator comes with scroll bars built in, as long as the table has a height set it will automatically add vertical scroll bars if the contents of the table is bigger than its height